# how to find the pipeline stages of a certain cpu？

Tags: c, pipeline, cpu-architecture

I did a performance experiment from https://en.algorithmica.org/hpc/pipelining/branching/

it says "We discard the pipeline, which is 19 cycles deep on Zen 2 (i.e., it has 19 stages, each taking one cycle)."

and I found the information from https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2

which give the following information:
[image]

but i only have PC with Apple M1 chip or intel i7 chip

i cannot find the specific pipeline stages of them

how to find the pipeline stages of a certain cpu？

and I found the information from https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2

Comment: *how to find the pipeline stages of a certain cpu?* - usually from info published by the vendor, in their optimization guide, marketing info, semiconductor conference presentations, or patents.  You can also attempt to measure branch mispredict latency which is related to the pipeline length, but doesn't measure stages after the one where mispredicts would be detected.  And out-of-order exec complicates things.